# Why does quicktime stop showing video

Tags: video, quicktime

Why does quicktime stop showing video

Running version 7.6.2 of quicktime

When I play my video every so often the video stops moving or goes away (still have audio).

Files are .mp4 format.

Would be great to have quick time work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html), both can read .mp4 files.

Without a GUI, mplayer will show a "console" window, which will give you more details on the file being played, and will indicate if there is a problem with it (file damaged, keyframe missing, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're on windows? You can install [Quicktime Alternative](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/quicktime_alternative.htm).

Or even better, and not windows-specific: you can install [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Plays .mp4 out of the box!

Comment: plays EVERYTHING out of the box! :P
I've never met a file VLC would play for me <3